# How do I enable Power Map in Excel 2013?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a heat map in Excel using Power Map. I have never used Power Map before. I have Office 2013 Professional Plus. Updates are pushed through by corporate IT. **The Map button does not appear on the Insert tab.**

- I have ensured the add-in is available and checked

[image: Excel COM Add-Ins]

- I have tried the 'Repair' option for my Microsoft Office product
- I have searched the 'Customize Ribbon' window for an option to add to the insert tab

I had a similar issue when I first installed Power View, but that was fixed by locating the correct command in the customize ribbon dialog window. I have not been able to do that for power map. Additionally, a full uninstall / reinstall of Office is not feasible.

Any ideas on how to get the Map button to appear on the Insert tab?

Comment: have you checked in to File => Options => Customize Ribbon, select All Tabs at the top, expend the +Insert tree item and see if +Power Map is listed there? The reason I ask is, it's the *only way* I've been able to see Power Map on the Customize Ribbon pane.  Going to All Commands and scrolling through the list *does not* show the Power Map tree item.

Comment: Well, that seemed to work. Now I am thoroughly confused because I was quite sure I checked that and did not see Power Map there. If you like add yours as an answer and I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: Added comment as an answer.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Map is a collection of commands and not a single command.  So going to the All Commands button, you will not see Power Map specifically but you will see the components of the Power Map listed individually (Launch Power Map, Add Selected Data to Power Map, and Map).  You cannot add these components individually unless you add a Custom Group.

In order to add the Power Map group, on the Customize Ribbon menu, select All Tabs and expand the Insert Tree Item.  You'll see the Power Map group, you can select the group and click Add.  Power Map will now be under the Insert group of the ribbon.